# Windows 7 default input language and Delphi 2010

Tags: windows, delphi

In windows 7, there is an option under
Region and Language --> Keyboards and Languages --> Change Keyboards --> General Tab:
"Select one of the installed input languages to use as the default for all input fields".

In my system the default is English.
I have also built an application in Delphi 2010 that users inputs data in english and Greek language. When i am navigating in forms the input language always change to the default one and this fact raises issues as following.

I have a grid with customers and search for one in greek language.
When I double click and opening a modal form with a specific customer's info for edit, the input language changes to English which is my default one.
Then I have to change the language to greek so I can edit customer's info.
When I close the modal form and return to Grid, language sets again to English.
I could set the windows defaut language to Greek but then I would have the same problem if the customer is in english language.

I dont know how to handle this in delphi. Another thought is to disable the windows option to automatically change the laguage to default but I dont know how this can be done.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `ActivateKeyboardLayout(...` in `TCustomDBGrid.WMKillFocus` in 'dbgrids.pas'. Is the breakpoing hit?

Comment: Anyway, check for yourself if it is the same issue: [Keyboard layout swtching when exiting dbgrid control](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79485).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe has nothing to do with Delphi. Delphi 2010 uses Unicode controls, so language is not an issue. This is an issue with being able to type Greek characters with a non-Greek keyboard. Or more generally, entering characters that a standard keyboard does not natively support.  Some languages simply require different types of input methods than the default. Such as using Input Method Editors (IMEs) to temporarily alter how keyboard keys are mapped so different input can be entered (think of typing Japanese or Chinese on a standard keyboard). This is a feature of Windows itself, outside the realm of Delphi.  This is simply how Windows itself works, there is nothing you have to do in your app to address or handle it.  It may be annoying at times, but this is part of how Windows supports internationalization.